# How to drive advantech CAN board in python?

Tags: python, can-bus, socketcan

I am using advantech's can board, model AMO-2203E.
I successfully installed the  driver(https://support.advantech.com/support/DownloadSRDetail_New.aspx?SR_ID=GF-GRSC&Doc_Source=Download) on ubuntu14.04, kernel 3.13 , and successfully sent and received with the provided sample program.
This program is written in C, I want to port it to my python project.
I know there is an open source Python-based CAN project (https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/), but it only supports the following interfaces, and there is no advantech support.

```
Socketcan
Kvaser’s CANLIB
CAN over Serial
CAN over Serial / SLCAN
IXXAT Virtual CAN Interface
PCAN Basic API
USB2CAN Interface
NI-CAN
isCAN
NEOVI Interface
Vector
Virtual
```

I guess I can add support for advantech based on this framework, but it feels a bit tricky for me.
  Another idea is to compile the C file for sending and receiving dynamic libraries, which are called by python for ctypes. This should be feasible.
I want to know if there is a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like Advantech provides both SocketCAN driver and another version probably for character device like interface. You just need to install the SocketCAN variant so that you get `can0` interface. As soon as it is working you can use python-can's [SocketCAN "driver"](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/interfaces/socketcan.html).